# How i can upload image to public folder in shared hosting laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I moved my website from localhost to shared hosting all it's good, but i need when i upload file  stored directly to public_html: something like this
public_html/storage/
 I tried use somenthing like :

```
symlink('/home/abdoweb/bmcelarave/storage/app/public', '/bmce/public_html/storage')
```

the problem still exists.

my Controller :

```
    public function addcategory(Request $request){

    $title = $request->input('category_name');
    $image = $request->file('category-image');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(storage_path().'/app/public/category',$name);
        $data[] = $name;

    $query=  DB::table('category')->insert(
        [
            'title' => $title,
            'image' => $name,
            "created_at" => Carbon::now()
        ]);
        if($query){
            return redirect('categories');
        }
}
```

My folder :

home/abdoweb/{bmcelaravel}  <= my public folder

Core laravel :

home/{bmce} <= core laravel

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can a use storage driver :

Inside config/filesystems.php :

```
'disks' => [
   'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
       'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
]

//Now you can move  the file to storage like : 

Storage::disk('public')->putFile('category', $request->file('category-image'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the recommended location for that stuff is to stay on the public path not creating a new one, unless there is an actual reason for that. Did you actually check that the symlink was created?

Laravel has an own command the create a symlink from `storage/app/public` to `public/storage` (the storage folder will be generated afterwards):

`php artisan storage:link`

But if you want to create defaults symlinks you should create one for yourself, like you already did.

This is the symlink pattern:

`ln -s target source` (fill in your target and source path)

So if you actually get the correct file from your request, this code should work:

```
Storage::putFile($name, $request->file('category-image'));
```

For more and detailed infos look into the filesystem [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)